# Subtracting numpy arrays of different shape efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Using the excellent broadcasting rules of numpy you can subtract a shape (3,) array `v` from a shape (5,3) array `X` with

```
X - v
```

The result is a shape (5,3) array in which each row `i` is the difference `X[i] - v`.

Is there a way to subtract a shape (n,3) array `w` from `X` so that each row of `w` is subtracted form the whole array `X` without explicitly using a loop?

Comment: What would be the shape of the output array?

Comment: We need to subtract n shape (3,) vectors from a shape (5,3) array so the result would be a shape (5,3,n) array.

Comment: I think it would be `(5,n,3)` rather, no? Because the last axis would be the rows.

Comment: In fact the ordering dosen't matter since I could use `swapaxes` the achieve the desired ordering (in my case (n,5,3)).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to extend the dimensions of `X` with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to form a 3D array and then do subtraction by `w`. This would bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) into play for this `3D` operation and result in an output with a shape of `(5,n,3)`. The implementation would look like this -

```
X[:,None] - w  # or X[:,np.newaxis] - w
```

Instead, if the desired ordering is `(n,5,3)`, then you need to extend the dimensions of `w` instead, like so -

```
X - w[:,None] # or X - w[:,np.newaxis]
```

Sample run -

```
In [39]: X
Out[39]: 
array([[5, 5, 4],
       [8, 1, 8],
       [0, 1, 5],
       [0, 3, 1],
       [6, 2, 5]])

In [40]: w
Out[40]: 
array([[8, 5, 1],
       [7, 8, 6]])

In [41]: (X[:,None] - w).shape
Out[41]: (5, 2, 3)

In [42]: (X - w[:,None]).shape
Out[42]: (2, 5, 3)
```