# Numpy Subtract two arrays of equal ndim but different shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have two ndarrays:

A with shape (N,a,a), a stack of N arrays of shape (a,a) basically

B with shape (8,M,a,a), a matrix of 8 x M arrays of shape (a,a)

I need to subtract B from A (A-B) such that the resulting array is of shape (8,M*N,a,a). 
More verbosely each (M total) of the 8 arrays of B needs to be subtracted from each array in A, resulting in 8*M*N subtractions between (a,a) shape arrays.

How can I do this in a vectorized manner without loops?
This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677183/subtracting-numpy-arrays-of-different-shape-efficiently) does something similar but in lower dimensions and I can't figure out how to extend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)
B = np.ones(shape=(8,4,2,2))
```

General broadcasting works if dimensions are the same or if one dimension is 1, so we do this;

```
a = A[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, :, :]
b = B[:, np.newaxis, :, :, :]

a.shape  # <- (1,2,1,2,2)
b.shape  # <- (8,1,4,2,2)
```

Now when you can do broadcasting

```
c = a - b
c.shape  # <- (8,2,4,2,2)
```

And when you reshape the (2x4=8) components get aligned.

```
c.reshape(8,-1,2,2)
```

The ordering of the new axes dictates the reshaping, so be careful with that.