# Why labels are not consistent with pandas, itertools, and numpy indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-itertools, multi-index

I cannot figure this out.  Why should the order of `group_A` matter during this situation?  `Ar_groupA` and `Ar_groupB` are indexed appropriately and are called in the correct order.

I'm using `pandas v0.24.2`

Please help me understand why the of the data in the groupings matter at all.

```
from collections import *
import itertools

def pairwise_logfc(df_data, group_A, group_B):
    # Init
    X = df_data.copy()
    attr_labels = X.columns

    # Log Transform
    df_log = np.log2(X)

    # Groups
    Ar_groupA = df_log.loc[group_A,:].values
    Ar_groupB = df_log.loc[group_B,:].values

    # Pairwise profiles
    logfc_profiles = list()
    for i in  range(len(group_A)):
        u = Ar_groupA[i,:]
        for j in range(len(group_B)):
            v = Ar_groupB[j,:]
            logfc_profiles.append(v - u)

    groups = (group_B, group_A)
    labels = [*itertools.product(*groups)]
    return pd.DataFrame(logfc_profiles, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(labels,names=["group_B", "group_A"]), columns=attr_labels)

# Load data
data = OrderedDict([('sepal_length', OrderedDict([('iris_0', 5.1), ('iris_1', 4.9), ('iris_10', 5.4), ('iris_100', 6.3), ('iris_101', 5.8), ('iris_102', 7.1), ('iris_103', 6.3), ('iris_104', 6.5), ('iris_105', 7.6), ('iris_106', 4.9), ('iris_107', 7.3), ('iris_108', 6.7), ('iris_109', 7.2), ('iris_11', 4.8), ('iris_110', 6.5), ('iris_111', 6.4), ('iris_112', 6.8), ('iris_113', 5.7), ('iris_114', 5.8), ('iris_115', 6.4), ('iris_116', 6.5), ('iris_117', 7.7), ('iris_118', 7.7), ('iris_119', 6.0), ('iris_12', 4.8), ('iris_120', 6.9), ('iris_121', 5.6), ('iris_122', 7.7), ('iris_123', 6.3), ('iris_124', 6.7), ('iris_125', 7.2), ('iris_126', 6.2), ('iris_127', 6.1), ('iris_128', 6.4), ('iris_129', 7.2), ('iris_13', 4.3), ('iris_130', 7.4), ('iris_131', 7.9), ('iris_132', 6.4), ('iris_133', 6.3), ('iris_134', 6.1), ('iris_135', 7.7), ('iris_136', 6.3), ('iris_137', 6.4), ('iris_138', 6.0), ('iris_139', 6.9), ('iris_14', 5.8), ('iris_140', 6.7), ('iris_141', 6.9), ('iris_142', 5.8), ('iris_143', 6.8), ('iris_144', 6.7), ('iris_145', 6.7), ('iris_146', 6.3), ('iris_147', 6.5), ('iris_148', 6.2), ('iris_149', 5.9), ('iris_15', 5.7), ('iris_16', 5.4), ('iris_17', 5.1), ('iris_18', 5.7), ('iris_19', 5.1), ('iris_2', 4.7), ('iris_20', 5.4), ('iris_21', 5.1), ('iris_22', 4.6), ('iris_23', 5.1), ('iris_24', 4.8), ('iris_25', 5.0), ('iris_26', 5.0), ('iris_27', 5.2), ('iris_28', 5.2), ('iris_29', 4.7), ('iris_3', 4.6), ('iris_30', 4.8), ('iris_31', 5.4), ('iris_32', 5.2), ('iris_33', 5.5), ('iris_34', 4.9), ('iris_35', 5.0), ('iris_36', 5.5), ('iris_37', 4.9), ('iris_38', 4.4), ('iris_39', 5.1), ('iris_4', 5.0), ('iris_40', 5.0), ('iris_41', 4.5), ('iris_42', 4.4), ('iris_43', 5.0), ('iris_44', 5.1), ('iris_45', 4.8), ('iris_46', 5.1), ('iris_47', 4.6), ('iris_48', 5.3), ('iris_49', 5.0), ('iris_5', 5.4), ('iris_50', 7.0), ('iris_51', 6.4), ('iris_52', 6.9), ('iris_53', 5.5), ('iris_54', 6.5), ('iris_55', 5.7), ('iris_56', 6.3), ('iris_57', 4.9), ('iris_58', 6.6), ('iris_59', 5.2), ('iris_6', 4.6), ('iris_60', 5.0), ('iris_61', 5.9), ('iris_62', 6.0), ('iris_63', 6.1), ('iris_64', 5.6), ('iris_65', 6.7), ('iris_66', 5.6), ('iris_67', 5.8), ('iris_68', 6.2), ('iris_69', 5.6), ('iris_7', 5.0), ('iris_70', 5.9), ('iris_71', 6.1), ('iris_72', 6.3), ('iris_73', 6.1), ('iris_74', 6.4), ('iris_75', 6.6), ('iris_76', 6.8), ('iris_77', 6.7), ('iris_78', 6.0), ('iris_79', 5.7), ('iris_8', 4.4), ('iris_80', 5.5), ('iris_81', 5.5), ('iris_82', 5.8), ('iris_83', 6.0), ('iris_84', 5.4), ('iris_85', 6.0), ('iris_86', 6.7), ('iris_87', 6.3), ('iris_88', 5.6), ('iris_89', 5.5), ('iris_9', 4.9), ('iris_90', 5.5), ('iris_91', 6.1), ('iris_92', 5.8), ('iris_93', 5.0), ('iris_94', 5.6), ('iris_95', 5.7), ('iris_96', 5.7), ('iris_97', 6.2), ('iris_98', 5.1), ('iris_99', 5.7)])), ('sepal_width', OrderedDict([('iris_0', 3.5), ('iris_1', 3.0), ('iris_10', 3.7), ('iris_100', 3.3), ('iris_101', 2.7), ('iris_102', 3.0), ('iris_103', 2.9), ('iris_104', 3.0), ('iris_105', 3.0), ('iris_106', 2.5), ('iris_107', 2.9), ('iris_108', 2.5), ('iris_109', 3.6), ('iris_11', 3.4), ('iris_110', 3.2), ('iris_111', 2.7), ('iris_112', 3.0), ('iris_113', 2.5), ('iris_114', 2.8), ('iris_115', 3.2), ('iris_116', 3.0), ('iris_117', 3.8), ('iris_118', 2.6), ('iris_119', 2.2), ('iris_12', 3.0), ('iris_120', 3.2), ('iris_121', 2.8), ('iris_122', 2.8), ('iris_123', 2.7), ('iris_124', 3.3), ('iris_125', 3.2), ('iris_126', 2.8), ('iris_127', 3.0), ('iris_128', 2.8), ('iris_129', 3.0), ('iris_13', 3.0), ('iris_130', 2.8), ('iris_131', 3.8), ('iris_132', 2.8), ('iris_133', 2.8), ('iris_134', 2.6), ('iris_135', 3.0), ('iris_136', 3.4), ('iris_137', 3.1), ('iris_138', 3.0), ('iris_139', 3.1), ('iris_14', 4.0), ('iris_140', 3.1), ('iris_141', 3.1), ('iris_142', 2.7), ('iris_143', 3.2), ('iris_144', 3.3), ('iris_145', 3.0), ('iris_146', 2.5), ('iris_147', 3.0), ('iris_148', 3.4), ('iris_149', 3.0), ('iris_15', 4.4), ('iris_16', 3.9), ('iris_17', 3.5), ('iris_18', 3.8), ('iris_19', 3.8), ('iris_2', 3.2), ('iris_20', 3.4), ('iris_21', 3.7), ('iris_22', 3.6), ('iris_23', 3.3), ('iris_24', 3.4), ('iris_25', 3.0), ('iris_26', 3.4), ('iris_27', 3.5), ('iris_28', 3.4), ('iris_29', 3.2), ('iris_3', 3.1), ('iris_30', 3.1), ('iris_31', 3.4), ('iris_32', 4.1), ('iris_33', 4.2), ('iris_34', 3.1), ('iris_35', 3.2), ('iris_36', 3.5), ('iris_37', 3.6), ('iris_38', 3.0), ('iris_39', 3.4), ('iris_4', 3.6), ('iris_40', 3.5), ('iris_41', 2.3), ('iris_42', 3.2), ('iris_43', 3.5), ('iris_44', 3.8), ('iris_45', 3.0), ('iris_46', 3.8), ('iris_47', 3.2), ('iris_48', 3.7), ('iris_49', 3.3), ('iris_5', 3.9), ('iris_50', 3.2), ('iris_51', 3.2), ('iris_52', 3.1), ('iris_53', 2.3), ('iris_54', 2.8), ('iris_55', 2.8), ('iris_56', 3.3), ('iris_57', 2.4), ('iris_58', 2.9), ('iris_59', 2.7), ('iris_6', 3.4), ('iris_60', 2.0), ('iris_61', 3.0), ('iris_62', 2.2), ('iris_63', 2.9), ('iris_64', 2.9), ('iris_65', 3.1), ('iris_66', 3.0), ('iris_67', 2.7), ('iris_68', 2.2), ('iris_69', 2.5), ('iris_7', 3.4), ('iris_70', 3.2), ('iris_71', 2.8), ('iris_72', 2.5), ('iris_73', 2.8), ('iris_74', 2.9), ('iris_75', 3.0), ('iris_76', 2.8), ('iris_77', 3.0), ('iris_78', 2.9), ('iris_79', 2.6), ('iris_8', 2.9), ('iris_80', 2.4), ('iris_81', 2.4), ('iris_82', 2.7), ('iris_83', 2.7), ('iris_84', 3.0), ('iris_85', 3.4), ('iris_86', 3.1), ('iris_87', 2.3), ('iris_88', 3.0), ('iris_89', 2.5), ('iris_9', 3.1), ('iris_90', 2.6), ('iris_91', 3.0), ('iris_92', 2.6), ('iris_93', 2.3), ('iris_94', 2.7), ('iris_95', 3.0), ('iris_96', 2.9), ('iris_97', 2.9), ('iris_98', 2.5), ('iris_99', 2.8)])), ('petal_length', OrderedDict([('iris_0', 1.4), ('iris_1', 1.4), ('iris_10', 1.5), ('iris_100', 6.0), ('iris_101', 5.1), ('iris_102', 5.9), ('iris_103', 5.6), ('iris_104', 5.8), ('iris_105', 6.6), ('iris_106', 4.5), ('iris_107', 6.3), ('iris_108', 5.8), ('iris_109', 6.1), ('iris_11', 1.6), ('iris_110', 5.1), ('iris_111', 5.3), ('iris_112', 5.5), ('iris_113', 5.0), ('iris_114', 5.1), ('iris_115', 5.3), ('iris_116', 5.5), ('iris_117', 6.7), ('iris_118', 6.9), ('iris_119', 5.0), ('iris_12', 1.4), ('iris_120', 5.7), ('iris_121', 4.9), ('iris_122', 6.7), ('iris_123', 4.9), ('iris_124', 5.7), ('iris_125', 6.0), ('iris_126', 4.8), ('iris_127', 4.9), ('iris_128', 5.6), ('iris_129', 5.8), ('iris_13', 1.1), ('iris_130', 6.1), ('iris_131', 6.4), ('iris_132', 5.6), ('iris_133', 5.1), ('iris_134', 5.6), ('iris_135', 6.1), ('iris_136', 5.6), ('iris_137', 5.5), ('iris_138', 4.8), ('iris_139', 5.4), ('iris_14', 1.2), ('iris_140', 5.6), ('iris_141', 5.1), ('iris_142', 5.1), ('iris_143', 5.9), ('iris_144', 5.7), ('iris_145', 5.2), ('iris_146', 5.0), ('iris_147', 5.2), ('iris_148', 5.4), ('iris_149', 5.1), ('iris_15', 1.5), ('iris_16', 1.3), ('iris_17', 1.4), ('iris_18', 1.7), ('iris_19', 1.5), ('iris_2', 1.3), ('iris_20', 1.7), ('iris_21', 1.5), ('iris_22', 1.0), ('iris_23', 1.7), ('iris_24', 1.9), ('iris_25', 1.6), ('iris_26', 1.6), ('iris_27', 1.5), ('iris_28', 1.4), ('iris_29', 1.6), ('iris_3', 1.5), ('iris_30', 1.6), ('iris_31', 1.5), ('iris_32', 1.5), ('iris_33', 1.4), ('iris_34', 1.5), ('iris_35', 1.2), ('iris_36', 1.3), ('iris_37', 1.4), ('iris_38', 1.3), ('iris_39', 1.5), ('iris_4', 1.4), ('iris_40', 1.3), ('iris_41', 1.3), ('iris_42', 1.3), ('iris_43', 1.6), ('iris_44', 1.9), ('iris_45', 1.4), ('iris_46', 1.6), ('iris_47', 1.4), ('iris_48', 1.5), ('iris_49', 1.4), ('iris_5', 1.7), ('iris_50', 4.7), ('iris_51', 4.5), ('iris_52', 4.9), ('iris_53', 4.0), ('iris_54', 4.6), ('iris_55', 4.5), ('iris_56', 4.7), ('iris_57', 3.3), ('iris_58', 4.6), ('iris_59', 3.9), ('iris_6', 1.4), ('iris_60', 3.5), ('iris_61', 4.2), ('iris_62', 4.0), ('iris_63', 4.7), ('iris_64', 3.6), ('iris_65', 4.4), ('iris_66', 4.5), ('iris_67', 4.1), ('iris_68', 4.5), ('iris_69', 3.9), ('iris_7', 1.5), ('iris_70', 4.8), ('iris_71', 4.0), ('iris_72', 4.9), ('iris_73', 4.7), ('iris_74', 4.3), ('iris_75', 4.4), ('iris_76', 4.8), ('iris_77', 5.0), ('iris_78', 4.5), ('iris_79', 3.5), ('iris_8', 1.4), ('iris_80', 3.8), ('iris_81', 3.7), ('iris_82', 3.9), ('iris_83', 5.1), ('iris_84', 4.5), ('iris_85', 4.5), ('iris_86', 4.7), ('iris_87', 4.4), ('iris_88', 4.1), ('iris_89', 4.0), ('iris_9', 1.5), ('iris_90', 4.4), ('iris_91', 4.6), ('iris_92', 4.0), ('iris_93', 3.3), ('iris_94', 4.2), ('iris_95', 4.2), ('iris_96', 4.2), ('iris_97', 4.3), ('iris_98', 3.0), ('iris_99', 4.1)])), ('petal_width', OrderedDict([('iris_0', 0.2), ('iris_1', 0.2), ('iris_10', 0.2), ('iris_100', 2.5), ('iris_101', 1.9), ('iris_102', 2.1), ('iris_103', 1.8), ('iris_104', 2.2), ('iris_105', 2.1), ('iris_106', 1.7), ('iris_107', 1.8), ('iris_108', 1.8), ('iris_109', 2.5), ('iris_11', 0.2), ('iris_110', 2.0), ('iris_111', 1.9), ('iris_112', 2.1), ('iris_113', 2.0), ('iris_114', 2.4), ('iris_115', 2.3), ('iris_116', 1.8), ('iris_117', 2.2), ('iris_118', 2.3), ('iris_119', 1.5), ('iris_12', 0.1), ('iris_120', 2.3), ('iris_121', 2.0), ('iris_122', 2.0), ('iris_123', 1.8), ('iris_124', 2.1), ('iris_125', 1.8), ('iris_126', 1.8), ('iris_127', 1.8), ('iris_128', 2.1), ('iris_129', 1.6), ('iris_13', 0.1), ('iris_130', 1.9), ('iris_131', 2.0), ('iris_132', 2.2), ('iris_133', 1.5), ('iris_134', 1.4), ('iris_135', 2.3), ('iris_136', 2.4), ('iris_137', 1.8), ('iris_138', 1.8), ('iris_139', 2.1), ('iris_14', 0.2), ('iris_140', 2.4), ('iris_141', 2.3), ('iris_142', 1.9), ('iris_143', 2.3), ('iris_144', 2.5), ('iris_145', 2.3), ('iris_146', 1.9), ('iris_147', 2.0), ('iris_148', 2.3), ('iris_149', 1.8), ('iris_15', 0.4), ('iris_16', 0.4), ('iris_17', 0.3), ('iris_18', 0.3), ('iris_19', 0.3), ('iris_2', 0.2), ('iris_20', 0.2), ('iris_21', 0.4), ('iris_22', 0.2), ('iris_23', 0.5), ('iris_24', 0.2), ('iris_25', 0.2), ('iris_26', 0.4), ('iris_27', 0.2), ('iris_28', 0.2), ('iris_29', 0.2), ('iris_3', 0.2), ('iris_30', 0.2), ('iris_31', 0.4), ('iris_32', 0.1), ('iris_33', 0.2), ('iris_34', 0.2), ('iris_35', 0.2), ('iris_36', 0.2), ('iris_37', 0.1), ('iris_38', 0.2), ('iris_39', 0.2), ('iris_4', 0.2), ('iris_40', 0.3), ('iris_41', 0.3), ('iris_42', 0.2), ('iris_43', 0.6), ('iris_44', 0.4), ('iris_45', 0.3), ('iris_46', 0.2), ('iris_47', 0.2), ('iris_48', 0.2), ('iris_49', 0.2), ('iris_5', 0.4), ('iris_50', 1.4), ('iris_51', 1.5), ('iris_52', 1.5), ('iris_53', 1.3), ('iris_54', 1.5), ('iris_55', 1.3), ('iris_56', 1.6), ('iris_57', 1.0), ('iris_58', 1.3), ('iris_59', 1.4), ('iris_6', 0.3), ('iris_60', 1.0), ('iris_61', 1.5), ('iris_62', 1.0), ('iris_63', 1.4), ('iris_64', 1.3), ('iris_65', 1.4), ('iris_66', 1.5), ('iris_67', 1.0), ('iris_68', 1.5), ('iris_69', 1.1), ('iris_7', 0.2), ('iris_70', 1.8), ('iris_71', 1.3), ('iris_72', 1.5), ('iris_73', 1.2), ('iris_74', 1.3), ('iris_75', 1.4), ('iris_76', 1.4), ('iris_77', 1.7), ('iris_78', 1.5), ('iris_79', 1.0), ('iris_8', 0.2), ('iris_80', 1.1), ('iris_81', 1.0), ('iris_82', 1.2), ('iris_83', 1.6), ('iris_84', 1.5), ('iris_85', 1.6), ('iris_86', 1.5), ('iris_87', 1.3), ('iris_88', 1.3), ('iris_89', 1.3), ('iris_9', 0.1), ('iris_90', 1.2), ('iris_91', 1.4), ('iris_92', 1.2), ('iris_93', 1.0), ('iris_94', 1.3), ('iris_95', 1.2), ('iris_96', 1.3), ('iris_97', 1.3), ('iris_98', 1.1), ('iris_99', 1.3)]))]) 

# 
X_iris = pd.DataFrame(data)
idx_groupA = X_iris.index[:5]
idx_groupB = X_iris.index[-10:]



pairwise_logfc(X_iris, sorted(idx_groupA), idx_groupB).loc[("iris_90", "iris_0")]
# sepal_length    0.108934
# sepal_width    -0.428843
# petal_length    1.652077
# petal_width     2.584963
# Name: (iris_90, iris_0), dtype: float64

pairwise_logfc(X_iris, sorted(idx_groupA)[::-1], idx_groupB).loc[("iris_90", "iris_0")]
# sepal_length   -0.050626
# sepal_width     0.000000
# petal_length   -0.280108
# petal_width    -0.547488
# Name: (iris_90, iris_0), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused.  When I do `df_log.loc[group_A,:]` each indice should be the same as `group_A` so `Ar_groupA[i,:]` should be represented by the ith element of `group_A`?

Comment: I was expecting them to be the same b/c of this line: `labels = [*itertools.product(*groups)]`.  I thought that the `group_A` and `group_B` would be properly combined.

Comment: I feel that I may either be miscommunicating or missing a crucial piece of logic.  `df_log` is a `pd.DataFrame` and has the original index of `X`.  `df_log.loc[group_A,:].values` should have the order of `group_A`.  The `i_th` element of `df_log.loc[group_A,:]` should be the same as the ith element of  `Ar_groupA`.  The label that corresponds to both should be `group_A[i]`.   Since `itertools.product`  is not sorted and is dependent on both input arrays (as expected), it should be the same whether or not I sorted `idx_groupA` before giving it to the function as `group_A`.  Right? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update. Get rid of the loops in "Pairwise profiles" altogether. We can use `numpy` broadcasting to do the subtraction in one line :D.

```
import numpy as np

def pairwise_logfc(df_data, group_A, group_B):
    # Init
    X = df_data.copy()
    attr_labels = X.columns

    # Log Transform
    df_log = np.log2(X)

    # Groups
    Ar_groupA = df_log.loc[group_A,:].values
    Ar_groupB = df_log.loc[group_B,:].values

    # Pairwise profiles
    logfc_profiles = np.vstack(Ar_groupB[:, None] - Ar_groupA)

    groups = (group_B, group_A)
    labels = [*itertools.product(*groups)]
    return pd.DataFrame(logfc_profiles, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(labels,names=["group_B", "group_A"]), 
                        columns=attr_labels)
```

---

```
pairwise_logfc(X_iris, sorted(idx_groupA), idx_groupB).loc[("iris_90", "iris_0")]
#sepal_length    0.108934
#sepal_width    -0.428843
#petal_length    1.652077
#petal_width     2.584963
#Name: (iris_90, iris_0), dtype: float64

pairwise_logfc(X_iris, sorted(idx_groupA)[::-1], idx_groupB).loc[("iris_90", "iris_0")]
#sepal_length    0.108934
#sepal_width    -0.428843
#petal_length    1.652077
#petal_width     2.584963
#Name: (iris_90, iris_0), dtype: float64
```

---

Original Fix:

You need to change the order for your `Pairwise` profiles logic. In your original, the outer loop is A, but when you define the groups its `product([B, A])`, so the outer loop needs to be `B`.

```
# Pairwise profiles
logfc_profiles = list()
for i in  range(len(group_B)):
    u = Ar_groupB[i,:]
    for j in range(len(group_A)):
        v = Ar_groupA[j,:]
        logfc_profiles.append(u - v)
```

Comment: @O.rka See the update for a nifty way to do the subtraction.

Comment: Wow, on my dataset the wall time dropped from 14.5s to 4.96s with the `np.new_axis`.  Can you describe a little how that can do the same thing as what we were doing before with the for loops?

Comment: @O.rka, that command is just a fancy alias for `None`, but the result is to add a new axis to your array. So if it's originally (10,4) it becomes (10,1,4). This allows us to use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) during a simple subtraction (10,1,4) - (5,4) such that we end up having a single vectorized subtraction instead of loops. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677183/subtracting-numpy-arrays-of-different-shape-efficiently) should be informative. `vstack` then stacks (10,5,4) to (50,4), 2D, so we can make a `DataFrame`