# comparing columns in two separate pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, both of which contain columns of latitude and longitude. For each lat/lon entry in the first dataframe, I want to evaluate each lat/lon pair in the second dataframe to determine distance.

For example:

```
df1:                     df2:

     lat     lon              lat     lon 
0   38.32  -100.50       0   37.65   -97.87
1   42.51   -97.39       1   33.31   -96.40
2   33.45  -103.21       2   36.22  -100.01

distance between 38.32,-100.50 and 37.65,-97.87
distance between 38.32,-100.50 and 33.31,-96.40
distance between 38.32,-100.50 and 36.22,-100.01
distance between 42.51,-97.39 and 37.65,-97.87
distance between 42.51,-97.39 and 33.31,-96.40
...and so on...
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

[**Euclidean Distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) is calculated as

[image: edpic]

You can do this with your two dataframes like this

```
((df1 - df2) ** 2).sum(1) ** .5

0    2.714001
1    9.253113
2    4.232363
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Euclidean distance doesn't really make sense as a direct measure between lat/long coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** as noted by @root it doesn't really make much sense to use Euclidean metric in this case, so let's use [sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html)

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
```

first we can build a DF with all  combinations - [(c) root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192792/5741205):

```
x = pd.merge(df1.assign(k=1), df2.assign(k=1), on='k', suffixes=('1', '2')) \
      .drop('k',1)
```

vectorized "haversine" distance calculation

```
x['dist'] = np.ravel(dist.pairwise(np.radians(df1),np.radians(df2)) * 6367)
```

Result:

```
In [86]: x
Out[86]:
    lat1    lon1   lat2    lon2         dist
0  38.32 -100.50  37.65  -97.87   242.073182
1  38.32 -100.50  33.31  -96.40   667.993048
2  38.32 -100.50  36.22 -100.01   237.350451
3  42.51  -97.39  37.65  -97.87   541.605087
4  42.51  -97.39  33.31  -96.40  1026.006744
5  42.51  -97.39  36.22 -100.01   734.219411
6  33.45 -103.21  37.65  -97.87   671.274044
7  33.45 -103.21  33.31  -96.40   632.004981
8  33.45 -103.21  36.22 -100.01   424.140594
```

**OLD answer:**

IIUC you can use pairwise distance [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html):

```
In [32]: from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

In [43]: from itertools import combinations

In [34]: X = pd.concat([df1, df2])

In [35]: X
Out[35]:
     lat     lon
0  38.32 -100.50
1  42.51  -97.39
2  33.45 -103.21
0  37.65  -97.87
1  33.31  -96.40
2  36.22 -100.01
```

as Pandas.Series:

```
In [36]: s = pd.Series(pdist(X),
                       index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple(combinations(X.index, 2))))

In [37]: s
Out[37]:
0  1     5.218065
   2     5.573240
   0     2.714001
   1     6.473801
   2     2.156409
1  2    10.768287
   0     4.883646
   1     9.253113
   2     6.813846
2  0     6.793791
   1     6.811439
   2     4.232363
0  1     4.582194
   2     2.573810
1  2     4.636831
dtype: float64
```

as Pandas.DataFrame:

```
In [46]: s.rename_axis(['df1','df2']).reset_index(name='dist')
Out[46]:
    df1  df2       dist
0     0    1   5.218065
1     0    2   5.573240
2     0    0   2.714001
3     0    1   6.473801
4     0    2   2.156409
5     1    2  10.768287
6     1    0   4.883646
7     1    1   9.253113
8     1    2   6.813846
9     2    0   6.793791
10    2    1   6.811439
11    2    2   4.232363
12    0    1   4.582194
13    0    2   2.573810
14    1    2   4.636831
```

Comment: Euclidean distance doesn't really make sense as a direct measure between lat/long coordinates.

Comment: @root, that's interesting - 'haversine' metric gives us close, but not exactly the same distances, compared to 'vincenty' method ...

Comment: Yes, the haversine formula is based on a spherical earth, but the earth isn't really a perfect sphere; it's slightly fatter around the equator (oblate spheroid).  The vincenty formula accounts for this.  In most cases haversine should be very close to vincenty, especially for relatively close distances.  The major differences would occur for points on opposite sides of the globe (antipodal points).

Comment: @root, thank you for that very detailed and clear explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a cross join to get all combinations of lat/lon, then compute the distance using an appropriate measure.  To do so, you can use the [`geopy`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/#) package, which supplies [`geopy.distance.vincenty`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/#geopy.distance.vincenty) and [`geopy.distance.great_circle`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/#geopy.distance.great_circle).  Both should give valid distances, with `vincenty` giving more accurate results, but being computationally slower.

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty

# Function to compute distances.
def get_lat_lon_dist(row):
    # Store lat/long as tuples for input into distance functions.
    latlon1 = tuple(row[['lat1', 'lon1']])
    latlon2 = tuple(row[['lat2', 'lon2']])

    # Compute the distance.
    return vincenty(latlon1, latlon2).km

# Perform a cross-join to get all combinations of lat/lon.
dist = pd.merge(df1.assign(k=1), df2.assign(k=1), on='k', suffixes=('1', '2')) \
         .drop('k', axis=1)

# Compute the distances between lat/longs
dist['distance'] = dist.apply(get_lat_lon_dist, axis=1)
```

I used kilometers as my units in the example, but others can be specified, e.g.:

```
vincenty(latlon1, latlon2).miles
```

The resulting output:

```
    lat1    lon1   lat2    lon2     distance
0  38.32 -100.50  37.65  -97.87   242.709065
1  38.32 -100.50  33.31  -96.40   667.878723
2  38.32 -100.50  36.22 -100.01   237.080141
3  42.51  -97.39  37.65  -97.87   541.184297
4  42.51  -97.39  33.31  -96.40  1024.839512
5  42.51  -97.39  36.22 -100.01   733.819732
6  33.45 -103.21  37.65  -97.87   671.766908
7  33.45 -103.21  33.31  -96.40   633.751134
8  33.45 -103.21  36.22 -100.01   424.335874
```

**Edit**

As noted by @MaxU in the comments, you can use a [numpy implementation of the Haversine formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545704/fast-haversine-approximation-python-pandas/29546836#29546836) in a similar manner for extra performance.  This should be equivalent to the `great_circle` function in `geopy`.

Comment: I think you can use [vectorized haversine formula](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29546836/5741205)

Comment: @MaxU: Thanks, I looked quickly for a haversine implementation but only found a pure python one.