# For large datasets in Python, how do I find the nearest location using longitude and latitude?

Tags: python, loops, scipy, latitude-longitude, large-data

I have a pandas dataframe containing **500.000**(!) rows (locations) and two columns:

- Longitude
- Latitude

Now I want a third column:

- Nearest location

This column should tell me which row/location is nearest to the 'current' row/location.

I know you can find the distance between two lon/lat using for example `cdist` from `scipy.spatial.distance`. However, this takes too much time, since it has to loop through the data set 500.000 * 500.000 times (because it tries to find the distance to each location, for every location).

Does anyone know how an appropriate way to deal with this?

Comment: Look up "sorting spatial data" or so on Google. It's out of scope for SO, but certainly a worthwhile and interesting subject.

Comment: Why does it need to be 500,000 * 500,000? Aren't you trying to find the nearest location from those 500,000 to some reference location?

Comment: Yes, so if you try to find the nearest location for one location, you need to loop through the dataset 500.000 times. However, I need to do this for every location in the data set. So: 500.000 * 500.000 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast Haversine Approximation (Python/Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545704/fast-haversine-approximation-python-pandas)

Comment: I understand that link is also going to be slow, but it's the best definitive approach I am aware of. Beyond that, I'm not sure it can be answered in the scope of SO