# How is this different behaviour possible? TypeError: unhashable type: 'Point'

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I try to find and filter the Points in a GeoDataFrame (df1) which are close to Points in a second GDF (df2), and vise versa.
I use this piece of code for it:

```
ps1 = []
ps2 = []
for p1 in df1.geometry:
    for p2 in df2.geometry:
        dist = haversine(p1.y,p1.x,p2.y,p2.x)
        if dist < 100:
            ps1.append(p1)
            ps2.append(p2)

df1 = df1[df1.geometry.isin(ps1)]
df2 = df2[df2.geometry.isin(ps2)]
```

However, I get an error on the last line:
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'Point'`

But the line above it works like a charm, and the data types of both lines (df1/df2 and ps1/ps2) are exactly the same.

How is that possible? And how can it be solved?

EDIT:

types of variables:

```
df1         :  <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
df1.geometry:  <class 'geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries'>
ps1         :  <class 'list'>
val1        :  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
df2         :  <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
df2.geometry:  <class 'geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries'>
ps2         :  <class 'list'>
```

EDIT 2:

```
df1.dtypes
Out[301]: 
lat                     float64
lon                     float64
time        datetime64[ns, UTC]
geometry               geometry
dtype: object

df2.dtypes
Out[302]: 
lat                     float64
lon                     float64
time        datetime64[ns, UTC]
geometry               geometry
dtype: object
```

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371000):
    """
    slightly modified version: of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29546836/2901002

    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees or in radians)

    All (lat, lon) coordinates must have numeric dtypes and be of equal length.

    """
    if to_radians:
        lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])

    a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
        np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2

    return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'lat': {0: 52.378851603519905,
  1: 52.37896949048437,
  2: 52.378654032960824,
  3: 52.37818902922923},
 'lon': {0: 4.88585622453752,
  1: 4.886671616078047,
  2: 4.886413945242339,
  3: 4.885995520636016},
 'time': {0: Timestamp('2019-11-05 11:31:42+0000', tz='UTC'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-11-05 11:32:22+0000', tz='UTC'),
  2: Timestamp('2019-11-05 11:32:49+0000', tz='UTC'),
  3: Timestamp('2019-11-05 11:33:31+0000', tz='UTC')}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'lat': {0: 52.378851603519905,
  1: 52.369466977365214,
  2: 52.36923115238693,
  3: 52.36898222465506},
 'lon': {0: 4.88585622453752,
  1: 4.9121331184582,
  2: 4.912723204441477,
  3: 4.913505393878495},
 'time': {0: Timestamp('2019-11-05 08:54:32+0000', tz='UTC'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-11-05 08:55:06+0000', tz='UTC'),
  2: Timestamp('2019-11-05 08:55:40+0000', tz='UTC'),
  3: Timestamp('2019-11-05 08:56:22+0000', tz='UTC')}})

df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1.lat, df1.lon))
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2.lat, df2.lon))

ps1 = []
ps2 = []
for p1 in df1.geometry:
    for p2 in df2.geometry:
        dist = haversine(p1.y,p1.x,p2.y,p2.x)
        if dist < 100:
            ps1.append(p1)
            ps2.append(p2)

val1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1)
val2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2)
# print(type(df1))
# print(type(df2))
# print(type(ps1))
# print(type(ps2))
print('df1         : ', type(df1))
print('df1.geometry: ', type(df1.geometry))
print('ps1         : ', type(ps1))
val1 = df1.geometry.isin(ps1)
print('val1        : ', type(val1))

print('df2         : ', type(df2))
print('df2.geometry: ', type(df2.geometry))
print('ps2         : ', type(ps2))
val2 = df2.geometry.isin(ps2)
print('val2        : ', type(val2))
# df1 = df1[df1.geometry.isin(ps1)]
# df2 = df2[df2.geometry.isin(ps2)]
```

Comment: Assign the index values to variables before indexing into `df1` and `df1`.  So `val1 = df1.geometry.isin(ps1)` and `val2 = df2.geometry.isin(ps2)`.  Then `print(type(val1))` and `print(type(val2))`.  See what they actually are.

Comment: Please, try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks; I added the result to the original question.

Comment: @Georgy I would like to, but how to include the original data?

Comment: See here: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/7851470)

Comment: Try also printing `df1.dtypes` and `df2.dtypes`.  I've had weird bugs where a stray string or NaN can change the type of the column, which changes the logic that certain library functions use.

Comment: `ps1` and `ps2` lists have zero elements each (in the MWE). Not sure what is expected from the `df1.geometry.isin(ps1)` call then.

Comment: @Keldorn Hm, that was a side-effect of MWE. Edited the data such that ps1 and ps2 are nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, Point is not hashable (since [this](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/614)?).

It turns out, for a reason I ignore, the `pandas.Series.isin` function seems to require the data to be hashable. See the [question I just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235207/pandas-isin-needs-hashable-data).

As for your question, a workaround would be to use lists, and convert it again to Series, like:

```py
val2 = pd.Series([v in ps2 for v in df2.geometry])
```

Comment: The version corresponds with mine (1.6.4.post2).
The workaround works, thanks for that! However, I still don't understand why ```df1.geometry.isin(ps1)``` does not fail, while ```df2.geometry.isin(ps2)``` does...