# pandas isin needs hashable data?

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

Does the `pandas.Series.isin` function require the data to be hashable? I did not find this requirement in the documentation ([Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) or [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), though I see the *index* needs to be hashable, not the data).

```py
foo = ['x', 'y']
bar = pd.Series(foo, index=['a', 'b'])
baz = pd.Series([foo[0]], index=['c'])
print(bar.isin(baz))
```

works as expected and returns

```
a     True
b    False
dtype: bool
```

However, the following fails with the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`:

```py
foo = [['x', 'y'], ['z', 't']]
bar = pd.Series(foo, index=['a', 'b'])
baz = pd.Series([foo[0]], index=['c'])
print(bar.isin(baz))
```

Is that intended? Is it documented somewhere? Or is it a bug in pandas?

Comment: Yes this is intended, list type object will make most of function in pandas do not work as expected

Comment: @YOBEN_S Is it documented? How about other (non list-type) non hashable objects?

Comment: You can convert to tuple

Comment: @YOBEN_S The example in the question is a basic version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230262/how-is-this-different-behaviour-possible-typeerror-unhashable-type-point/61235373#61235373) stressing the root of the issue. In that case, the user has no control over the key (of type `shapely.geometry.point.Point`, used by geopandas). I would have naively expected that the existence of a `__eq__` operator was sufficient for `isin` to work. Where can I see that this is intended and not a bug?