# Looping through lat lon with Haversine function comparing to one lat lon

Tags: python, distance, haversine

I have two dataframes, one with many rows of `lat`/`lon` points like so:

```
lat            lon   
32.8000009     -117.536
32.800005      -117.047   
etc...
```

We'll call this `df1`,

and a `df` with only one `lat`/`lon` point (we'll call it `df2`)

```
Ycoord     Xcoord 
32.8005     -117.0473
```

I am trying to use the haversine function to loop through the first dataframe for every `lat` `lon` point and find the distance from those to the second `df`.

I was able to use code to figure out how to loop through the first `df` using the `haversine` function and calculate the distance from one point to the next and putting these in a new column, but how do I loop through the first `df` while comparing to this second `df` (with only one pair of points) instead of the previous point?

Here is the previous code I was using:

```
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371):
"""
slightly modified version: of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29546836/2901002

Calculate the great circle distance between two points
on the earth (specified in decimal degrees or in radians)

All (lat, lon) coordinates must have numeric dtypes and be of equal length.

"""
if to_radians:
   lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(np.radians,[lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2])

a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
    np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2

return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))


df['distKM_cleaned'] = \
haversine(df.lat.shift(), df.lon.shift(),
             df.loc[1:, 'lat'], df.loc[1:, 'lon'])
df['distMI_cleaned'] = df['distKM_cleaned'] * 0.621371
#distKM is in km, distMI is converted to miles
df.tail()
```

and the output I got looked like this:

```
lat            lon            distMI_cleaned
32.8000009     -117.536       0
32.800005      -117.047       .0003450
etc...
```

So my question is how to create this new column, similar to distMI_cleaned but dist_from_df2 as a new column?
Sorry, I am completely new to all of this and have googled everything to even get this far.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to manually type in the lat lon points from df2 (here as lon1, lat1) and this is what worked for me!

```
def haversine(row):
lon1 = -117.047343
lat1 = 32.800027
lon2 = row['lon']
lat2 = row['lat']
lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
c = 2 * np.arcsin(sqrt(a)) 
km = 6367 * c
return km

df['distance_from_HomeMI'] = df.apply(lambda row: haversine(row), axis=1) * 0.621371
```