# Pandas dataframe : working with Latitude and longitude features

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have total 32 variables in dataframe,

- X1 to X16 - Latitude values and
- Y1 to Y16 - Longitude values for 16 different positions.

I want to perform following steps on these values using python,

- calculate distance between each position (X1,Y1) with every other position. Do it for all the positions and then average the distance.
- e.g., calculate distance between (X1,Y1) & (x2,y2), (X1,Y1) & (x3,y3), (x1,y1)&(x4,y4) etc - then average distance(A1)
- calculate distance between (X2,Y2) & (x1,y1),(X2,Y2) & (x3,y3) etc - then average distance (A2)...etc
- Finally i want to take the mean of A1+A2+...+A16 and insert in a column for corresponding rows.

I want to do it to compare the final column (mean of A's) with dependent variable.

I know there is something like following code to work with latitude and longitude but dont know how can i use it in my case.

## vectorized haversine function

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371):
"""
slightly modified version: of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29546836/2901002

```
Calculate the great circle distance between two points
on the earth (specified in decimal degrees or in radians)

All (lat, lon) coordinates must have numeric dtypes and be of equal length.

"""
if to_radians:
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])

a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
    np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2

return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
```

df['dist'] = haversine(df.LAT.shift(), df.LONG.shift().df.loc[1:, 'LAT'], df.loc[1:, 'LONG'])

Answer (score 0):

The below should help you to find the distance between two coordinates:

```
# Python 3 program to calculate Distance Between Two Points on Earth
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2):
     
    # The math module contains a function named
    # radians which converts from degrees to radians.
    lon1 = radians(lon1)
    lon2 = radians(lon2)
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
      
    # Haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
 
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    
    # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    r = 6371
      
    # calculate the result
    return(c * r)
     
     
# driver code
lat1 = 53.32055555555556
lat2 = 53.31861111111111
lon1 = -1.7297222222222221
lon2 =  -1.6997222222222223
print(distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2), "K.M")
```

To find the same, for all the positions, using a 'for' loop should help you. It can be there stored in a new column and the mean can be calculated.

**Edited:**
I am sure the below code will help you. I have created a sample dataset as per your requirement and worked on it. Since you are new to python, I did the whole code for you. Let me know if this is your requirement - attaching the sample dataset, code, and output for you.

Sample input/dataset : [sample dataset that i created as per your requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWxYA.png)

Sample Output : [sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y5Ma.png)

```
import pandas as pd
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

df = pd.read_excel(r'sample.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

#function to calculate the distance
def distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2):
     
    # The math module contains a function named
    # radians which converts from degrees to radians.
    lon1 = radians(lon1)
    lon2 = radians(lon2)
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
      
    # Haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
 
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    
    # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    r = 6371
      
    # calculate the result
    return(c * r)
     
     
#driver code
#finds the number of rows in df
df_len = df.shape[0]

dist_list = []

#'for' loop that iterates through the every rows of the dataframe
for i in range(df_len):
    dist_list = []
    for j in range(df_len):
        val1 = df.iloc[[i]]
        lat1 = int(val1['x'])
        lon1 = int(val1['y'])
        
        val2 = df.iloc[[j]]
        lat2 = int(val2['x'])
        lon2 = int(val2['y'])
        
        #function calling to calculate the distance between the (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), and so on.
        dist_btwn = distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2)
        
#         appending the distance to a "dist_list"
        dist_list.append(dist_btwn)
    
    col_name = "dist between ({}, {}) and every other points".format(lat1,lon1)
    df[col_name] = dist_list

#lets now print the dataframe
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. Since i am new to python how can use above code to work on python dataframe using for loop.

Comment: Can you please attach edited code? I do not have just one X & Y column.. I have 16 X(latitude) columns & 16 Y(longitude) columns & there values in one row. & I want to calculate the distance as discussed above.

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed adding it. Please see the attached edited code now.

Comment: How do i make it work for 32 lat/long columns? I have latitude columns from X1 to X16 and longitude columns Y1 to Y16.

Comment: Change your range in the 'for' loop. Do you mind attaching a screenshot of what your dataset looks like? So that I can have better clarity to guide you better.

Comment: i cant attach screenshot but i have 32 position variables. (first 16 are latitude and next 16 are longitude) for 16 different position. I want to find average distance of every position(X1,Y1) with every other position upto (X16,Y16).
|X1| X2|...|X16|Y1|Y2|...|Y16| are my 32 columns.